# How can I add an ice maker water line?

Tags: plumbing, water, valve

I have the following setup with a T with a valve to an above sink water filter. 
[image]

The line from the T has one steel braided 3/8” line and goes up to the sink as 3/8”. The other is a thin PVC line with a valve that goes to the above sink water filter. I would like to add an Ice Maker 1/4” steel braided line to the mix. I prefer to take advantage of the valve that is used by the above sink water filter. I have been trying to find a 1/4” T, but all ends are male. I can’t find a T with one end female and the other male or a 1/4” coupler. I don’t want to add another supply line nor mess with copper tubing. 
What recommendations can you give me?

Other Parts I currently have:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to achieve what you are looking for with what you already have is to:

1. Shut off the water at the angle stop shown in your first photo
   (confirm that the valve is closed by opening the cold on you sink)
2. Cut the copper tubing in half (the tubing between the angle stop and
   the second valve)
3. Install the valve tee shown in your second photo (this will reconnect the cut tube)
4. Test (by opening the angle valve)
5. Slowly tighten the compression fittings if they are leaking

Here's a video on how to install compression fittings: [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQGL8MBLlaE).

Comment: I didn't want to mess with the cooper since I don't have the necessary tools, but it seems logical and more leak proof. Apart from a copper tube cutter what other tools would I need? I am not too keen on cutting the working copper; I might buy a foot or less at my local hardware store and play with that. What size copper tube, brass flange, and nut would I need?

Comment: The copper tube in question is 3/8". The only tools that you'll need is a copper tube cutter and two crescent wrenches. This is a simple task, but the best advise is to take it slow and don't over tighten anything. When using the tube cutters, don't tighten them too quickly as you can deform the tube. When tightening the compression nuts, again, don't over tighten them as you can always tighten them more if they drip a little.

Answer (score 3):

*The following that I posted earlier probably will not work as explained by pdd:*

Why not connect the male end on the existing T to the male end on a second T with a simple female to female coupling such as this:

[image: coupling]

These are available as a standard item in home centers and plumbing supply stores.

*I do think pdd's solution is a good one, but I think the connector I listed in the comment will also work.*

Comment: I had gone to Home Depot and the associate showed me a [T](http://tinyurl.com/cj6opud) and tried to test fit it with the [coupler](http://tinyurl.com/d64y3kz), but apparently the thread was different and didn't match.

Comment: Perhaps this might work:  [T-fitting][1]


  [1]: http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-202309860/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=compression%20fitting%20coupler&storeId=10051

Comment: The fittings in the original post are compression type and have a running thread. The coupling shown here has National Pipe Threads and are not compatible.

Comment: @pdd - I like your approach. Simple, effective.